# New SharePoint 2010 install Error - Failed on SQL 2008 Native Client

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, sql, sql-express

I'm undertaking a new installed to replicates and excising infrastructure to test updating to new SharePoint server e.g. 2016, etc. When I try and install SharePoint 2010 Foundation on a windows server 2021 R2 (fully patched) when undertaking the installation prerequisites it fails when trying to installed the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client and as it no longer available on the MS website link. I'm having a trouble locating so my question is

(1) dose anyone know of a website the archives old clients such as this?
(2) have a copy the can put in OneDrive \ GDrive and share the link to download?
(3) Alternative install, e.g. use SQL server express as an alternative?

I haven't done this before so any assistance would be most apricated. Watch a few YouTube however they have the client or could download it at the time of recording.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57606? Note that SharePoint 2010 is out of support and is no longer receiving any form of security updates.

Comment: I understand all that however I need answers not more questions to be honest. As mentioned it's for a client and I have to build regardless of New and shinny options, etc. If there is no solution offered then please refrain from needing to inform me that it is not supported, as I know this. However if you have positive vibes of let's resolve and use our collective knowledge then power to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution: downloaded a feature pack and extracted the spncli files or something like that it's called. I installed all of them however 3 failed and one worked so I now have a new working share point 2010 server running as standalone install. I'll try with farm installation and using sql server 2008 express and see what happens. I'll update with links to the native feature pack I used to extract the files later.